# grad_outputs in Chainer vs grad in Tensorflow for backward function

Tags: tensorflow, chainer, automatic-differentiation

I want to translate some custom operation with self-defined gradient from Chainer to Tensorflow. The forward pass is relatively straightforward, I already have it. But for the backward pass, I can never make the optimization works. Let's suppose the backward pass in Chainer is this:

```
def backward_gpu(self, inputs, grad_outputs):
    return some_operation(inputs, grad_outputs[0])
```

I did this in Tensorflow in the following way:

```
@tf.RegisterGradient('Forward')
def _rasterize_grad(op, grads):
    return some_operation(op.inputs, grads[0])
```

Based on the docs I find online, I think the `grad_outputs` and `grads` are computed the same way. But somehow I failed.

Can anyone shed some light on this? That would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I think your question is for tensorflow, and not for chainer.
But I have a comment for the backward of chainer. When you want to get input of function in backward operation, you need retain input in `forward` pass and get input by calling `self.get_retained_inputs()` in `backward` operation.
https://github.com/chainer/chainer/blob/master/chainer/functions/connection/linear.py#L59
https://github.com/chainer/chainer/blob/master/chainer/functions/connection/linear.py#L77

Comment: Yeah, thanks for this! And can you give more comment on the difference between the backward pass in Chainer and Tensorflow? To me seems they provide the same functionality, but somehow directly naive translation doesn't work.